# Can I await a string change?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, uwp, async-await, task

I have an UWP App that has an PDFReader in it.
The PDFReader has a search window. After entering a word in the search textbox you are able to start the search. Currently it is so that if you start the search you have to wait 3 seconds till you see a message how often the word occurs.

Now I want to fill those 3 seconds with a "Searching..." message.

One solution I had was this:

```
private async void DoSearch(...)
{
//...
Task<string> searchingText = setSearchMsg();
infoBox.Text = await searchingText;
//...
}

private async Task<string> setSearchMsg()
{
infoBox.Text = "Searching...";
await Task.Delay(1);
return "";
}
```

But this just does not look right. One thing I noticed is when I'm looking for a word and the word can be found like 3000 times in 80 pages the `infoBox` skips the "Searching..." message and again fills the infoBox with emptiness.
To fix this I could change the `Task.Delay` to like `Task.Delay(100)` which cannot be the right solution I assume.

Comment: Can you give the signature for `searchText`?

Comment: @Enigmativity Yes. Sorry about that. 'searchText' was meant to be 'searchingText'. Edited that mistake

Comment: Now your code looks very confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like your search logic is blocking the main thread and doesn't contain any `await` statements and therefore never yields control. This means that the message loop that handles repainting the label is not having a chance to run consistently, so you get inconsistent display results.

I suggest moving the search logic into its own method and calling it asynchronously on the thread pool. Keep the display logic in your existing method but use `Task.Run` to execute a separate method that performs the actual search.

```
private async void DoSearch(...)
{
    infoBox.Text = "Searching....";
    await Task.Run( () => DoActualSearch() );
    infoBox.Text = "";
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You should use Microsoft's Reactive Framework (aka Rx) - NuGet `System.Reactive.Windows.Threading` and add `using System.Reactive; using System.Reactive.Linq;` - then you can do something amazing.

I mocked up a bit of code similar to yours. I started with a `TextBox` and `TextBlock` and a dummy method for performing a search:

```
    private async Task<string> PerformSearchAsync(string text)
    {
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2.0));
        return "Hello " + text;
    }
```

Now, in the constructor, after `this.InitializeComponent();` I created the following observable that responds to all of the `TextChanged` events on my `textBox1`:

```
        IObservable<EventPattern<TextChangedEventArgs>> textChanges =
            Observable
                .FromEventPattern<TextChangedEventHandler, TextChangedEventArgs>(
                    h => textBox1.TextChanged += h,
                    h => textBox1.TextChanged -= h);
```

Then I wrote a query to respond to the text changes:

```
        IObservable<string> query =
            textChanges
                .Select(x =>
                    Observable
                        .FromAsync(() => PerformSearchAsync(textBox1.Text))
                        .StartWith("Searching..."))
                .Switch();
```

This is essentially waiting for each text change and initiating an async call to `PerformSearchAsync` - which will return the search results as a string - and it also immediately returns the string `"Searching..."`. The `.Switch()` is used to make sure only the latest call to `PerformSearchAsync` actually returns a result.

Now I can simply observe the query:

```
        _subscription =
            query
                .ObserveOnDispatcher()
                .Subscribe(x => textBlock1.Text = x);
```

The variable `_subscription` is defined as `private IDisposable _subscription = null;`. It is used so that I can call `_subscription.Dispose()` to safely close down the subscription.

It behaves the way you want.

My whole code looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reactive;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

namespace App5
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        private IDisposable _subscription = null;

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            IObservable<EventPattern<TextChangedEventArgs>> textChanges =
                Observable
                    .FromEventPattern<TextChangedEventHandler, TextChangedEventArgs>(
                        h => textBox1.TextChanged += h,
                        h => textBox1.TextChanged -= h);

            IObservable<string> query =
                textChanges
                    .Select(x =>
                        Observable
                            .FromAsync(() => PerformSearchAsync(textBox1.Text))
                            .StartWith("Searching..."))
                    .Switch();

            _subscription =
                query
                    .ObserveOnDispatcher()
                    .Subscribe(x => textBlock1.Text = x);
        }

        private async Task<string> PerformSearchAsync(string text)
        {
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2.0));
            return "Hello " + text;
        }
    }
}
```

You should be able to adapt this to work with your code.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the "Searching..." message *isn't* the async part of your code - it's instantaneous. It's the search that actually takes time, right? But what you're doing is setting the message... waiting... and immediately *clearing* the message. You need to set the message, do the slow operation, then clear the message.

It should be something like this:

```
private async void DoSearch(...)
{
   // Before starting the heavy-duty async operation.
   infoBox.Text = "Searching...";

   // Do the search. Infobox should display "Searching..." throughout.
   await pdfReader.SearchAndHighlightWords(searchString);

   // Now we're back from the slow async operation. Clear the infobox.
   infoBox.Text = "";
}
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you so far. Just to be sure a bit more information about DoSearch: At the beginning when I started the DoSearch() methode it was set like this: infoBox.Text = "Searching"... -> Get number of hits of the word that is searched -> Jump to the location of the first word -> infobox.Text "1 word out of x" (x being the number of all searched words). But instead of setting "Searching..." instantly there would be nothing. I had to wait for 2 seconds and then I would just reach the last step. How can this be explained?

Answer (score 1):

This code snippet should work. The magic is change your Text, before awaiting.

If search performed too quickly and text changes also quickly, you can add a small delay say 100ms for every search, because for user no matter to wait 3 seconds or 3.1 seconds.

```
private async void DoSearch(...)
{
//...
infoBox.Text="Searching..."
var result= await SearchTextAsync();
//await Task.Delay(100ms); //add this if your search can perform too quickly to avoid flickering effect
infoBox.Text = result;// or clean
//...
}
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you so far. Just to be sure a bit more information about DoSearch: At the beginning when I started the DoSearch() methode it was set like this: infoBox.Text = "Searching"... -> Get number of hits of the word that is searched -> Jump to the location of the first word -> infobox.Text "1 word out of x" (x being the number of all searched words). But instead of setting "Searching..." instantly there would be nothing. I had to wait for 2 seconds and then I would just reach the last step. How can this be explained?